# Searching for string in all columns of dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a string in all columns of a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'a']], columns=["A", "B"])

for col in df:
        df[col].str.contains('a')

0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

However, the code above returns only the booleans and not the format that I want (displays the rows and columns in table form), which can be achieved when searching in a specific column:

```
df[df.A == 'a']

   A  B
0  a  b
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create boolean `DataFrame` and check at least one `True` per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.eq('a').any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   A  B
0  a  b
2  e  a
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.eq('a'))
       A      B
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False   True

print(df.eq('a').any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

---

If want check `substring`s use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for `boolean DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['ad', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'asw']], columns=["A", "B"])
print (df)
    A    B
0  ad    b
1   c    d
2   e  asw

df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('a')).any(axis=1)]
```

Or [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elemnt wise checking by `in`:

```
df = df[df.applymap(lambda x: 'a' in x).any(axis=1)]

print (df)
    A    B
0  ad    b
2   e  asw
```

Comment: what about searching mutiple strings?

Comment: @JunchenLiu - then use `df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('a|b|c')).any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using the aptly named `np.logical_or`.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'a']], columns=["A", "B"])

mask = np.logical_or.reduce([df[col] == 'a' for col in df])

df[mask]

#    A  B
# 0  a  b
# 2  e  a
```

This method is also adaptable to `str.contains`. Fore example:

```
mask = np.logical_or.reduce([df[col].str.contains('a', na=False) for col in df])
```